# Getting a Object Property and lowering its case using map()

Tags: javascript

i have a object

```
  // the global variable
   var watchList = [
    {
    "Title": "Inception",
    "imdbRating": "8.8",
  },
  {
    "Title": "Interstellar",
    "imdbRating": "8.6",
    },
  {
    "Title": "The Dark Knight",
    "imdbRating": "9.0",
    },
  {
    "Title": "Batman Begins",
    "imdbRating": "8.3",
    },
  {
    "Title": "Avatar",
    "imdbRating": "7.9",
     }
];
```

i am using map () like this

```
var ratings = [];
  ratings = watchList.map(
    ({Title, imdbRating}) => ({Title, imdbRating }));

console.log(JSON.stringify(ratings));
```

i am getting output like this :-

```
 [{"Title":"Inception","imdbRating":"8.8"},{"Title":"Interstellar","imdbRating":"8.6"},{"Title":"The Dark Knight","imdbRating":"9.0"},{"Title":"Batman Begins","imdbRating":"8.3"},{"Title":"Avatar","imdbRating":"7.9"}]
```

but i need object result like this

```
[{"title":"Inception","rating":"8.8"},{"title":"Interstellar","rating":"8.6"},{"title":"The Dark Knight","rating":"9.0"},{"title":"Batman Begins","rating":"8.3"},{"title":"Avatar","rating":"7.9"}]
```

watchList is a global variable .cannot change it .i know i can use toLowerCase function but i have no idea how to imply that in map function .

Comment: In destructuring assignment `=> ({Title, imdbRating }))`, your variable name will be the key. So either rename the extracted value like `({ Title: title }) =>` or assign value on hardcoded key: ` => ({ title: Title, ... })`

Comment: You are mapping array to itself!

Comment: it was the first time i used map() i am learning javascript functional programming :) @VahidAlimohamadi

Comment: @Rajesh got it we can give it any name like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just rename the properties by [assigning to new variable names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names).

```js
var watchList = [{ Title: "Inception", imdbRating: "8.8" }, { Title: "Interstellar", imdbRating: "8.6" }, { Title: "The Dark Knight", imdbRating: "9.0" }, { Title: "Batman Begins", imdbRating: "8.3" }, { Title: "Avatar", imdbRating: "7.9" }],
    ratings = watchList.map(({ Title: title, imdbRating: rating }) => ({ title, rating }));

console.log(ratings);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
const ratings = watchList.map(({Title, imdbRating}) => ({ title: Title, rating: imdbRating }));

console.log(JSON.stringify(ratings));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var watchList = [
    {
    "Title": "Inception",
    "imdbRating": "8.8",
  },
  {
    "Title": "Interstellar",
    "imdbRating": "8.6",
    },
  {
    "Title": "The Dark Knight",
    "imdbRating": "9.0",
    },
  {
    "Title": "Batman Begins",
    "imdbRating": "8.3",
    },
  {
    "Title": "Avatar",
    "imdbRating": "7.9",
     }
];
var fixed = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(watchList).replace(/imdbRating/g, 'rating'))

console.log(fixed)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  // the global variable
   var watchList = [
    {
    "Title": "Inception",
    "imdbRating": "8.8",
  },
  {
    "Title": "Interstellar",
    "imdbRating": "8.6",
    },
  {
    "Title": "The Dark Knight",
    "imdbRating": "9.0",
    },
  {
    "Title": "Batman Begins",
    "imdbRating": "8.3",
    },
  {
    "Title": "Avatar",
    "imdbRating": "7.9",
     }
];

let ratings = watchList.map(({Title, imdbRating})=>({title: Title, rating:imdbRating}));

console.log(ratings);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var ratings = [];

_.map(watchList, (obj) => ratings.push({'Title': obj.Title, rating: obj.imdbRating}));
```

You could use the map function from the underscore library and simply rename the keys of the object within the map function and push them to your empty array like in this example above.

Comment: This gets the correct output. Reviewed it. Anyone can print this answer to the console and will see the output the OP is asking for.